# Drupal 6 querying multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Having some trouble with the Drupal 6 query syntax. My query works fine on its own:

```
SELECT term_node.tid, term_data.name FROM term_node, term_data WHERE nid = 22640
```

Below is what I have when I convert it for use with drupal 6:

```
$currentTIDs = db_query("SELECT {term_node}.tid, {term_data}.name FROM {term_node}, {term_data} WHERE nid = 22640");

while ($cTids = db_fetch_object ($currentTIDs)) {
array_push($currentTIDsArray, $cTids);
}

drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($currentTIDsArray, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

This results in an empty query / array? Any Ideas?

Comment: Never used drupal but have you tried not wrapping the tables in `{ }`?

Comment: Hey Supericy, check out the $currentTIDs line, you'll see both tables have the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
SELECT tn.tid, td.name FROM {term_node} tn, {term_data} td WHERE nid = 22640");
```